# I am trying to expose an angular 8 project with module federation to another angular project that is angular 15, is that possible? if so any pointers?

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

Trying to mfe an angular 8 project to an angular 15 shell project, both running separately just fine.
I tried installing module federation to my angular 8 projects, but immediately errores emerged, is it even possible to use module federation in angular 8 project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Module federation is a Webpack 5 feature](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#module-federation). Angular 8 uses Webpack 4. Experimental support for Webpack 5 was added in Angular 11, stable support in Angular 12, see the [Angular v12 release notes](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49).

It may be possible with a custom build, but not with the Angular CLI.

Comment: Dang it, by now i have read every module-federation article i can find, and tried different versions, i tried angular 14, angular 15 also works great, i might load them in a git as example later.  But this has rly given me a headache!  Thank you for your answer...really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you maybe have any pointers how i can make the custom bild?

Comment: It will be a lot of effort, building an Angular application from scratch is not trivial. I guess it would be easier upgrading the project to Angular 11 or higher.

Comment: i will be trying the upgrade, because i can't build the angular 8 project from the beginning. Thank you again for your help! Much appreciated.